# Check constraint on generic interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface, subclass, superclass

I have an interface as follows:

```
public interface IHasDetailPage<TViewModel> where TViewModel : ViewModelBase 
{
    TViewModel GetViewModel();
}
```

Later on in my code, I have an object which I know implements this interface. However, at compile-time, I do know know the specific type argument it uses. I would like to retrieve the ViewModel of that object, by calling the above function:

```
ModelBase Target = DbHelper.Find(... // Retrieves this object from the database
if(Target is IHasDetailPage<ViewModelBase>)
{
    ViewModel = (Target as IHasDetailPage<ViewModelBase>).GetViewModel();
}
```

Again, I know `Target` implements `IHasDetailPage`, and that the ViewModel is a subclass of `ViewModelBase`. But this if-statement fails, and if I remove it, the cast fails (returns `null`). I assume because Target doesn't implement `IHasDetailPage<ViewModelBase>` specifically, but `IHasDetailPage<SpecificViewModel>`, even tough `SpecificViewModel : ViewModelBase`.

How can I perform this type check and cast properly? Really, all I need is to be able to call `GetViewModel()`, but I would like to understand how this can be properly done, and why my approach doesn't work.

Comment: What is `ModelBase` here?

Comment: It's a base class that every model inherits from. At compile-time I don't know  the specific type. This inheritance tree is unrelated to the ViewModelBase inheritance tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have control over the interface, you can make it covariant. The following test passes...

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void DetailPage_ShouldBeOfFooType()
    {
        var target = new Target();
        Assert.IsTrue(target is IHasDetailPage<Foo>);
    }

    public class Foo { }
    public class Bar : Foo { }
    public interface IHasDetailPage<out TViewModel> where TViewModel : Foo
    {
        TViewModel GetViewModel();
    }
    public class Target : IHasDetailPage<Bar>
    {
        public Bar GetViewModel() { return null; }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I added `out` to the interface type declaration, and it works now. I didn't know about covariance, but I looked it up now and it seems very useful; I wish I'd known about it a long time ago!